# Add item to selection listbox on button click

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have setup a WPF with several listboxes and an add button:

```
    <Window x:Class="QuickSlide_2._0.Window1"
    x:Name="load_style"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:self="clr-namespace:QuickSlide_2._0"
    xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    Title="Load_style" Height="300" Width="300" MinHeight="720" MinWidth="1280" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="#B0000000" AllowDrop="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ShowInTaskbar="False">

  <Grid>

    <Rectangle Height="720" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="#00000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1280" MinHeight="320" MinWidth="380" Fill="DarkGray"/>


    <ListBox Height="241" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="502,371,0,0" Name="Presentation_slide_items" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="199" />

    <ListBox Name="subjects_list" Margin="74,154,1039,171" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=styles_list, Path=SelectedItem.subjects}"/>
    <ListBox Name="sub_subjects_list" Margin="264,154,849,171" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=subjects_list, Path=SelectedItem.sub_subjects}"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="styles_list" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="74,112,0,0"/>
    <ListBox Name="user_inputs" Margin="502,154,565,421" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=sub_subjects_list, Path=SelectedItem.possible_input, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Name="TextBoxList" Text="{Binding input}" BorderThickness="0" />                     
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button x:Name="button_add_input" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="502,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" Command="{Binding ElementName=sub_subjects_list.add_input} />
</Grid>
```

Now I want to add an additional user_input to the list in the user_inputs listbox when clicking on the button "button_add_input". I have been searching and it looks like using the "command" option of the button could be the way to go. 
This is my class "sub_subject"

```
        public class sub_subject
{
    public string short_name { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool read_from_db { get; set; }
    public string table_name { get; set; }
    //public ObservableCollection<string> possible_input { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<possible_input> possible_input { get; set; }

    public sub_subject(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;

        possible_input = new ObservableCollection<possible_input>();
        //possible_input = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void add_input()
    {
        possible_input input = new possible_input();
        input.input = "";
        possible_input.Add(input);
    }
}
```

I was thinking I can add a function to the class that adds a possible_input to the ObservableCollection and calling this function in the command of the button. But I just cannot figure out how to setup the proper command. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that sub_subject is the viewmodel (the datacontext) of the window (the view).

In this case you should add a Command class to your project. This is an implementation of the ICommand. You can find an implementation of the ICommand here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

After that you will have to create a property in your viewmodel for the command that calls the add_input method. Then, bind your command property to the Command property of the button.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction Niels. This looks like the way to go, will give it a try!